# Hibernate OneToMany and ManyToOne confusion! Null List!

Tags: java, database, hibernate, persistence, entity-relationship

I have two tables...
For example - Company and Employee (let's keep this real simple)

```
Company( id, name );
Employee( id,  company_id );
```

Employee.company_id is a foreign key.

My entity model looks like this...

**Employee**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
Company company;
```

**Company**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

So, yeah I want a list of employees for a company.

When I do the following...

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setCompany(c); //c is an Company that is already in the database.
DAO.insertEmployee(e); //this works fine!
```

If I then get my Company object it's list is empty!

Ive tried endless different ways from the Hibernate documentation!

Obviously not tried the correct one yet!

I just want the list to be populated for me or find out a sensible alternative.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to make the relationship bidirectional. Yours is two unidirectional ones. Add `mappedBy = "company"` to `employeeList`. This tells hibernate the employee list is simply the reverse of the ref from `Employee` to `Company`

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "company")
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the fast reply!

I did this but I am still seeing an empty list.

Any more ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to remove the join column from this spec though.

Comment: Thanks again but I am still seeing an empty list. Is it possible that hibernate is not updating to the db or not fetching the latest version? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should do 
`List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();`
This should be done when you have defined the side which has the list as the owning side which in your case is the Employee and not the Company. I think each time you load the Company instance, you are being supplied with a new instance of employeeList, not sure though. But surely, there is no need to instantiate the new ArrayList each time.